# Canvas3D not appearing in Swing window

Tags: java, swing, java-3d

I am attempting to insert a Canvas3D object inside a Swing JPanel, but the code doesn't seem to be working (i.e. nothing happens):

```
        Canvas3D canvas = new Canvas3D(SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration());
        SimpleUniverse universe = new SimpleUniverse(canvas);
        BranchGroup root = new BranchGroup();
        root.addChild(new ColorCube());
        universe.addBranchGraph(root);
        universe.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();
        canvasPanel.add(canvas);
```

What am I missing? The JPanel was created using NetBean's Visual Editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you have to set a layout manager on the panel, which automatically expands the child components to the full area. A JPanel has a FlowLayout by default, which *does not* expand the child components. You could try a BorderLayout instead by calling:

```
canvasPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

Answer (score 0):

Canvas3D needs a size passed to it; setting the preferred configuration from SimpleUniverse is not enough. In my case, that meant this code:

```
        // 3D canvas initialization
        Canvas3D canvas = new Canvas3D(SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration());
        SimpleUniverse universe = new SimpleUniverse(canvas);
        BranchGroup root = new BranchGroup();
        root.addChild(new ColorCube());
        universe.addBranchGraph(root);
        universe.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();
        canvas.setSize(100, 100);
        canvasPanel.add(canvas);
```